# There has to be a better way of parsing XML in C# than what I'm doing

Tags: c#, xml

This is the way I'm currently getting data from XML, but it seems to be really inefficient, checking every localname in every iteration. How should I be doing it?

Here is a sample of the XML I am trying to parse, followed by my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <result>
    <properties type="array">
      <property>
        <last-account-review-at>2011-04-26 00:00:04</last-account-review-at>
        <unit-balance type="integer">-104</unit-balance>
        <daily-consumption type="decimal">10.8</daily-consumption>
        <status>active</status>
        <end-date></end-date>
        <icp-number>0001234567RN602</icp-number>
        <address>
          <property-name nil="true"></property-name>
          <flat-number>3</flat-number>
          <suburb>Suburbia</suburb>
          <street-number>21</street-number>
          <region>Nether</region>
          <street-name>Easy</street-name>
          <district>Metropolis</district>
        </address>
        <start-date>2010-05-05</start-date>
        <status-detail nil="true"></status-detail>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <account-number>9001234567</account-number>
  </result>
  <version>1.0</version>
</hash>
```

I don't have any issues with the maintainability of my code, it's more that it seems like I shouldn't be comparing against so many things at every iteration.

```
public static class DataRetrieval
    {

        private static XmlNameTable _nt;
        private static object _propertyElement;
        private static object _unitBalanceElement;
        private static object _dailyConsumptionElement;
        private static object _statusElement;

        static DataRetrieval()
        {
            _nt = new NameTable();
            _propertyElement = _nt.Add("property");
            _unitBalanceElement = _nt.Add("unit-balance");
            _dailyConsumptionElement = _nt.Add("daily-consumption");
            _statusElement = _nt.Add("status");
        }      

        public static bool ParseCustomerData(string raw, out List<PropertyDetails> properties)
        {
            bool parsedOK = false;
            properties = new List<PropertyDetails>();
            PropertyDetails property = null;

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.NameTable = _nt;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(raw), settings);

            object localname;

            bool continueReading = true;
            int dataItemsRead = 0;
            const int DataItemsToRead = 3;

            try
            {

                while (continueReading)
                {
                    if (reader.IsStartElement())
                    {
                        localname = reader.LocalName;

                        if (localname == _propertyElement)
                        {
                            if (property != null)
                            {
                                if (dataItemsRead == DataItemsToRead)
                                {
                                    properties.Add(property);
                                    dataItemsRead = 0;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            property = new PropertyDetails();
                            continueReading = reader.Read();

                        }
                        else if (localname == _unitBalanceElement)
                        {
                            property.UnitBalance = reader.ReadElementContentAsInt();
                            dataItemsRead++;
                        }
                        else if (localname == _dailyConsumptionElement)
                        {
                            property.DailyConsumption = reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                            dataItemsRead++;
                        }
                        else if (localname == _statusElement)
                        {
                            if (property.SetStatus(reader.ReadElementContentAsString()))
                            {
                                dataItemsRead++;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continueReading = reader.Read();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continueReading = reader.Read();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (XmlException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("XmlException: {0}", e.Message);
            }

            parsedOK = dataItemsRead == DataItemsToRead;

            if ((property != null) && (parsedOK))
            {
                properties.Add(property);
            }

            return parsedOK;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead.

It would also help to see an example of the `xml` you're trying to parse in order to properly suggest a refactoring of your code.

EDIT:
You could do this (`XDocument` + `LINQ`):

```
string sXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                <hash>
                  <result>
                    <properties type=""array"">
                      <property>
                        <last-account-review-at>2011-04-26 00:00:04</last-account-review-at>
                        <unit-balance type=""integer"">-104</unit-balance>
                        <daily-consumption type=""decimal"">10.8</daily-consumption>
                        <status>active</status>
                        <end-date></end-date>
                        <icp-number>0001234567RN602</icp-number>
                        <address>
                          <property-name nil=""true""></property-name>
                          <flat-number>3</flat-number>
                          <suburb>Suburbia</suburb>
                          <street-number>21</street-number>
                          <region>Nether</region>
                          <street-name>Easy</street-name>
                          <district>Metropolis</district>
                        </address>
                        <start-date>2010-05-05</start-date>
                        <status-detail nil=""true""></status-detail>
                      </property>
                    </properties>
                    <account-number>9001234567</account-number>
                  </result>
                  <version>1.0</version>
                </hash>";

var xml = XDocument.Parse(sXml);

var r = from x in xml.Descendants("property")
        select new 
        {
            unitBalance = x.Element("unit-balance").Value,
            dailyConsumption = x.Element("daily-consumption").Value,
            status = x.Element("status").Value
        };

this._propertyElement = xml.Descendants("property");
this._unitBalanceElement = r.ElementAt(0).unitBalance;
this._dailyConsumptionElement = r.ElementAt(0).dailyConsumption;
this._statusElement = r.ElementAt(0).status;
```

***Note: I didn't include any error checking, just wanted to show some possibilities.***

Comment: Personally i love XDocument with linq it provides cleaner and better options.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at

> [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb387065.aspx) (MSDN)

The venerable [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) has a nice piece of Linq to XML [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/07/using-linq-to-xml-and-how-to-build-a-custom-rss-feed-reader-with-it.aspx). That should help get you started!

Using Linq to XML should definately make your code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e dealing with a given scheme definition in .xsd you can use the [xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to generate matching classes. Using those generated classes provides type safety.
[Here](http://www.codingday.com/xml-c-class-generator-for-c-using-xsd-for-deserialization/) you can find an easy example.

If you don't like xsd.exe [xsd2code](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) is another alternative for code generation.